# Cannot access docker container when network=host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I was using Docker Desktop on MacOS.

I launched a postgres instance on host machine, so I chose to use `network=host` mode.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6-alpine3.12
RUN apk --update add build-base nodejs tzdata git \
    postgresql-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev \
    yarn libcurl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN gem install bundler
WORKDIR /var/www/root
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3001
CMD bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001
```

The application could run locally

```
→ bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.6 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
Use Ctrl-C to stop

→ netstat -na|grep 3001
tcp4       0      0  *.3001                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

But when I built and ran it in container, it did not listen to port. I checked in container, it listened inside container but did not expose port. When I tried to explicitly expose the port, it warned me this was disgarded in `network=host` mode.

```
→ docker run --rm --network host -it rails-demo
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.6 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
Use Ctrl-C to stop

→ netstat -na|grep 3001
<nothing>

→ docker exec -it 69020de7b8b5 ash
/var/www/root # netstat -na|grep 3001
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

→ docker run --rm -p 3001:3001 --network host -it rails-demo
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.6 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Comment: What is your host OS?  What "kind" of Docker are you using?  (Native Docker on Linux, Docker Desktop, Docker Toolbox?)  You shouldn't usually need host networking, especially for a straightforward HTTP application.

Comment: @DavidMaze Updated, macos, docker desktop. I considered using it for development

Comment: [Host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) "only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac".